# How do I transfer data from console log to a json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a script that outputs data to console. log, how can I put data from console.log in a separate json file?

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

 store.search({
    term: 'ninja',
    num: 2,
    page: 3,
    country : 'us',
    lang: 'lang'
    })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: you use appropriate file functions from [noedjs fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: can you clarify one thing. Are you able to edit the script or do you need to figure out how to solve this problem through an external mean. Depending on that the answer will differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fs module as:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonData = {}    // Your Json data 
fs.writeFile ("output.json", JSON.stringify(jsonData), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('complete');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around is to use `>>` operator

```
node your_file.js >> file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.search({
    term: 'ninja',
    num: 2,
    page: 3,
    country : 'us',
    lang: 'lang'
})
.then(response => {
    fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(response));
})
.catch(err => {
    fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(err));
});
```